# implementing edge triggered reset in verilog without initial block

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm trying to add an edge_triggered reset to my `module`, meaning that only if a transient from 0 to 1 detected in `reset`, the reset operation should be perform.
and further more, I don't want to use any `initial` block in my module (because I think initial blocks have issues in FPGAs).

finally, I decided to following something like this:

```
always @ (posedge clock, posedge reset) ...
```

but the problem I encountered, is that I need to know which element of `always block` sensitivity list is activated.

also I think this method isn't a proper solution:

```
always @ (posedge clock, posedge reset) begin
    if(reset) begin
        //doing reset operations
    end
.
.
.

end
```

because if `reset` is 1 from previous clocks (not transient from 0 to 1) in next `posedge clock` the reset operation will be perform! but we didn't want this.

so, is there any way to find out which element of sensitivity list activated the `always block`?
or even any other solution for implementing edge_triggered reset?

Comment: AFAIK there is no digital element that reacts on **two** clocks, and your desired edge-triggered reset is a clock. Did you do some research on the matter? Would it help if you have an edge detector that outputs a synchronous reset? -- Oh, and why did you tag VHDL _and_ Verilog?

Comment: I edited my post and removed `vhdl` tag, but about your first part of speech, isn't asynchronous resets common? i just want this but only in edges. i think its possible

Comment: Think about a D flip-flop that you are setting and resetting asynchronously. Then you can wire the reset to the clock input and set the data input to low. Voila, an edge-triggered reset, potentially with lower priority than "set" and "reset". I used to use a similar design to catch edges.

Comment: Flip-flops commonly have an asynchronous reset, right, which can be synchronized in an extra flip-flop. So you _need_ a level to reset your logic, if you want a separate clock. -- You can get away with some hacky design that uses propagation delay to generate a pulse from an edge. However, this dependents heavily on at least voltage and temperature. The "clean" way is a clocked edge detector. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

There almost certainly isn't a primitive in your FPGA that will do exactly what you want. And even in simulation, you wouldn't be able to tell which of the edges in the sensitivity list triggered the update.

The code you posted should synthesize, but as you noted it will behave like a standard asynchronous reset and continue to reset as long as `reset` is high. In order to reset only on the `reset` rising edge, you'll need some clock domain crossing logic to detect the edge and output a single pulse on the `clock` domain.

For example:

```
// This module can assert reset_pulse asynchronously but must output a pulse
// for at least one 'clock' cycle and deassert synchronously.
async_edge_to_pulse e2p (
    .in_edge   (reset),
    .out_clock (clock),
    .out_pulse (reset_pulse)
);

always @(posedge clock or posedge reset_pulse) begin
    if (reset_pulse) begin
        // reset logic
    end else begin
        // operational logic
    end
end
```